# James Joule's Conservation of Energy

Tags: specific-reference, energy-conservation, history

Is there a manifest or documentation of the original Conservation of Energy as stated by James Joule word for word?

**Edit 1.1:**
I found Joule's Memoir on [google](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=bX8EAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&authuser=0&hl=en&pg=GBS.PA3), skimming through to find any conclusive evidence.